# same color code but one is lighter then other

Tags: html, css

in the example below background and border is `#007399`
the same code is for `.title:hover`
but on hovering the text color is obviously much lighter then the border
what is the reason?

```css
.title{
background:#007399;
line-height:25px;
border:2px solid #007399;
color:white;
letter-spacing:1px;
text-align:center;
}

.title:hover{
background:white;
color:#007399;
}
```

```html
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: optical illusion?

Comment: the color is not actually lighter, its an optical illusion because your eye takes the contrast to compare.

Comment: Optical illusion + font smoothing.

Comment: hey its because your border is 2px solid

Comment: let the text bold if you want it looking darker

Comment: @tacoshy - the contrast is the same. Both, border and  text are the same color and the same (white) background - meaning - the same contrast

Comment: @qadenza if you talk about the pure color as value yes. But the eye does not take a pure color. it also takes the space size into effect changing the effective contrast.